# Bootstrap 4 ajax loaded modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, bootstrap-4

I am migrating from BS3 to BS4.1

In my apps I do use ajax loaded modals.

In layout I have

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalToFillInfo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalToFillInfoLabel" aria-hidden="true">
</div>
```

Then button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" title="Informace o uživateli" onclick="showUserDetail(@u.Id)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalToFillInfo">
   <i class="fas fa-info" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

and simple JS func

```
showUserDetail = function (id) {
    $.get('/Uzivatel/ModalUserInfo/' + id,
        function (data) {
            $('#myModalToFillInfo').html(data);
        });
}
```

Func load for example this

```
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

So its makes a example modal togather. Thanks to data-toggle and target it auto opens the modal.

Problem is that close buttons dosen't work.

Same code was working in BS3.

Doesn anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Is your get request event loading any content at all inside your modal? I mean, assigning a anonymous function to a variable `showUserDetail` is different from naming a function `showUserDetail(id) { }`

Comment: No, the function is exactly the same 
button - onclick="showUserDetail(@id)"
calls jquery function
showUserDetail = function (id){
...
}

Comment: Did you update both your `.css` as your `.js` bootstrap files?

Comment: yes, started new project from scratch

Comment: All I can think then is either your GET request is either failing or looping infinitely and you probably isn't catching the `fail (data) { }` function to show you the proper return or you just need to force reload your browser to clean the bootstrap files from cache and download the latest.

Comment: Problem solved. I forgot layout=null in partial modal page.

Answer (score 0):

```
we manually close the bootstrap modal like

  <div class="modal" id="AddQueModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close closeModel" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data- 
  dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>

<script>
 $(".closeModel").click(function() {
    $('#AddQueModal').modal('toggle');
 });
</script>
```